# Get "real" HTML source from website

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I've come across an issue where my favorite radio station plays a song I don't know while I'm driving.  They don't have one of those pages that shows a list of songs that they've played; however, they do have a "Now Playing" section on their site that shows what's currently playing and by who. So, I am trying to write a small program that will poll the site ever 2 minutes to retrieve the name of the song and the artist.  Using Chrome dev tools, I can see the song title and artist in the source.  But when I view the page source, it doesn't show up.  They are using a javascript to run display that info. I've tried the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(@"http://www.thebuzz.com/main.html");

    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
                                 WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
         // Do nothing while we wait for the page to load
    }
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Loading);

    var test = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
    textBox1.Text = test.ToString();
}
```

Essentially, I'm loading it into a `WebBrowser` and trying to get the source this way.  But I'm still not getting the part after the javascript is run.  Is there a way to actually retrieve the rendered HTML after the fact?

**EDIT**

Also, is there a way in the `WebBrowser` to allow scripts to run?  I get popups asking me if I want to allow them to run.  I don't want to suppress them, I need them to run.

Comment: Why not just use Shazam or SoundHound?

Comment: What about using a tool like Tunatic or Shazam? It's much easier :)

Comment: Because sometimes those things don't work.  Also, if I did that, I wouldn't learn how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried actually waiting until the WebBrowser window is fully loaded (in the WF app, of course) and you can see the name of the song, then running your code?

Comment: Sounds like they are using a AJAX call to poll the current playing song. In your chrome dev tools look at the XHR traffic in the Network section. You may be able to simply make the AJAX request to get the song.

Comment: Maybe you should check for `e.Url == "http://www.randomwebsite.com/main.html"`.

Comment: This is probably going to be easier if you link us the site.

Comment: @JayTomten: I can see the traffic, but when I try to run the link going through, I get a "Navigation Cancelled" page, and it attempts to download something.

Comment: @Arran: Done. Thought I had. :(

Comment: They're getting their current playing list by ajax from `http://ktbz.s.widget.ldrhub.com/new/api/now_playing/ktbz/` you can find the request in your devtools in the "network" panel.

Comment: @godesign: Yeah, I got that. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Jay Tomten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835228/get-real-html-source-from-website/14835780#comment20787319_14835228) said in the comments, you're trying to fix the result of your problem, not the cause. The cause of the problem is that they're using Javascript to update that part of the page. Instead of working around that by letting the Javascript do its update and then reading what it wrote, ask yourself where the Javascript is getting the info from and whether you can go to the same place. Open up something that lets you see web traffic - [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), or Chrome's dev console, for example. Watch for POST calls. One of them will likely be an AJAX request in which the Javascript on the page is getting the current song. Note the URL, inspect the call to see what parameters it sends and what data it gets back. You can use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) or something like it to assemble a POST request and work out how the Javascript on that site is getting its data, and then write a little code to make your own call to that URL and parse what comes back.

Comment: Yeah, I finally figured it out, following Jay's suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: I did.  Though he only made a comment, so it doesn't count toward rep.